# How to remove the build error with arch wizard in angular?

Tags: angular, sass

I am using `angular-archwizard": ^5.0.0`. libray in my angular app. It works fine. When taking the build it shows the error. My angular version is `8.2.4`

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: As of Dart Sass 2.0.0, !global assignments won't be able to
declare new variables. Since this assignment is at the root of the stylesheet,
the !global flag is unnecessary and can safely be removed.

   ╷
44 │ $wz-param-indicator-state: null !global;
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/angular-archwizard/variables.scss 44:1  @import
    node_modules/angular-archwizard/archwizard.scss 1:9  @import
    stdin 3:9                                            root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: As of Dart Sass 2.0.0, !global assignments won't be able to
declare new variables. Since this assignment is at the root of the stylesheet,
the !global flag is unnecessary and can safely be removed.

   ╷
47 │ $wz-param-indicator-color: null !global;
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/angular-archwizard/variables.scss 47:1  @import
    node_modules/angular-archwizard/archwizard.scss 1:9  @import
    stdin 3:9                                            root stylesheet
```

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] /home/gitlab-runner/builds/gxJwAPyJ/0/bricx/bricx-web/dist/bricx/common-es2015.e490dce0636f4faf1660.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/gxJwAPyJ/0/bricx/bricx-web/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
See "/tmp/ng-ge6GLz/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```